# Plotting histogram error - want to swap x and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have an array with values [100,101,102,103,104,105]. When I am plotting it on histogram the values 100,101... are coming on x axis but i want them on y...any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: It is recommended to post some code to show what you tried (as well as some sample of data) when asking the question.

Comment: You will get better results if you check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: can you add a picture (handmade eventually), or a description  of your input and desired output?

Answer (score 1):

First of all are you sure you want the histogram. By definition the histogram will have values vs count of occurrences. If indeed want the histogram, but with rotated axis it can be done using 'orientation' keyword.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vals = np.random.randint(100,110,(100))
print(vals)
plt.hist(vals, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Following further clarifications looks like you want horizontal bar plot. Using your example I modified it just to use `barh()` instead of `bar()` and also added another source of data, otherwise the result is too trivial. For bar plot you need two columns - one is the position of the bar, another is the length of the bar.

```
array = [101,102,103,104,105]
values = np.random.randint(0,10, size=len(array))
print(values)
plt.barh(array,values)
plt.show()
```

Output:
`[3 9 2 4 7]`

[image]

Comment: I actually want bar chart but its giving me flat lines of same length.

Comment: Well, that's because if your dataset has only unique value the histogram will be flat lines, again, based on the definition. If you want bar chart - you need x-positions and some y-values. Your question is not clear - you really need to post data and code of what you tried.

Comment: My code is array = [101,102,103,104,105] plt.bar(array,height=1, width=0.8) plt.show()

Comment: Updated. With your dataset and your example you can just use plt.hbar(), but the result will be trivial. You need second column with length of the bars.